# How to write a program to separate 1 to one side and 0 to one side in a binary string in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Could you please let me know how write a program to separate 1 to one side and 0 to one side in a binary string in mysql?

example,
101010 to 111000

Comment: Did you try anything for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach, using `REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT bin_str,
       CONCAT(REPLACE(bin_str, '0', ''), REPLACE(bin_str, '1', '')) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo